# How to find all dates between two dates in Zend Framework Query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I need to find all dates between two dates; that is start date and end date. Here is my query but it is not doing what I need it to do.

In my table I have column name `date_created` which is in format like this `2011-06-09 06:41:10`. I want to remove this portion `06:41:10` so I am applying

```
DATE(date_created)
```

After that as my datepicker is in this format `02/07/2012` I change the format through `DATE_FORMAT()` .

`$start_date and $end_date` are my variables coming for comparing and in format of `02/07/2012`

```
$select = $DB->select()
->from('sms', array(
    'sms_id',
    'sms_body',
    'sms_sender',
    'sms_recipient',
    'date_created',
    'sms_type'))
->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
->where("DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date_created), '%m/%d/%Y') >= ?",  $start_date)
->where("DATE_FORMAT(DATE(date_created), '%m/%d/%Y') <= ?",  $end_date)
->order("".$option_call_log." ".$option_call_log_asc_desc);
```

What am I missing in the query? Why is it not comparing $start_date and $end_date?
Forget about `$option_call_log` and `$option_call_log_asc_desc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your dates are coming through in the format MM/DD/YYYY, then rather than getting MySQL to do all the work I'd convert them to YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS in PHP, which allows you to do a straightforward range based query in MySQL. So:

```
$start_date_formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($start_date)).' 00:00:00';          
$end_date_formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).' 00:00:00';

$select = $DB->select()
    ->from('sms', array('sms_id','sms_body','sms_sender','sms_recipient','date_created','sms_type'))
    ->where('phone_service_id = ?', $phone_service_id)
    ->where("date_created >= ?",  $start_date_formatted)
    ->where("date_created <= ?",  $end_date_formatted)
    ->order("".$option_call_log." ".$option_call_log_asc_desc)
    ;
```

(If the dates in your date picker are actually in DD/MM/YYYY format then things are a little more fiddly.)

Comment: DJ Fountain saved my life, why is this never spoken about in ZF2 docs?

Answer (score 1):

update change hours to include the last day
$end_date_formatted = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($end_date)).' 23:59:59';